# How can I customize bindings in ninject

Tags: ninject

I'd like to 'any interface that inherits one or more interfaces from this list of interfaces' to a specific provider using ninject 2.  Would an implementation of IBindingResolver be appropriate here?

Comment: So you would like to bind all implementations of interface I in your app to the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no - use ninject.extensions.conventions instead

```
kernel.Bind(
    x => x.FromThisAssembly()
          .SelectTypesInheritedFrom<IMyInterface>()
          .BindToAllInterfaces()
          .Configure((c, s) => c.InSingletonScope()));
```

Comment: While this is the best answer to the question asked, I'm not sure it's going to work for me.  I'm looking at OpenGenericBindingResolver as an example at this point.

Comment: I have 3 assemblies: Domain defines interfaces, Data defines implementations, Web consumes. Say Domain defines IFoo and IBar.  A controller in Web which consumes both will define IFooBar and consume that.  Ideally what I'd like to do is detect those aggregate interfaces and return an intercepting proxy which delegates calls to the individual implementations.  I dont see how I'd do that with the extensions convention.

Comment: @JeffreyABecker You would have to write your own IBindingGenerator to bind the interfaces to your proxy in that case. 

But do you really want to du such an ugly thing? What for? Why don't you just inject IFoo and IBar separately into the controller? Is this just a workaround for reducing the number of dependencies? In that case solve the actual problem which is most likely that you don't follow the SRP.

Comment: I completely agree with you on not doing SRP here.  Mostly this is an attempt to get a mind-blowingly bad code base to somewhere better.  The original code had a grand-unified repository which we've been able to separate out into 12 or so separate interfaces.  Controller / route re-factoring is scheduled for a future sprint.

Comment: @JeffreyABecker In that case I wouldn't workaround the problem with the long constructor initialization list. Just add all of them now and get it better at a later time by refactoring your controller. Combining the interfaces to make the constructor smaller is just a hack.